# Google Drive push notifications

Tags: google-drive-api, webhooks

I'd like to use the `/watch` ([doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/watch)) API endpoint for subscribing a remote url to receive informations about changes in Google Drive.

The webhook received doesn't contain any body as specified in the documentation but contains headers which should help to understand what happened on the user's account.

Problem is that the headers doesn't contain [anything useful](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69726632) and contains [incorrect values too](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69661750).

I'm saving a pageToken that I'm using to retrieve changes but when receiving multiple concurrent requests there's an high risk to receive the same change twice.

Is there a safe way to understand what happened hook by hook?

Comment: Did you provide the [required properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#making-watch-requests) ?

Comment: @noogui yes, I get a 200 status code from the webhook registration, problem is related to the data received from the Google webhook.